# Changing "Lost Password Email Link" to custom password reset page

Tags: redirect, login, hooks

On the Wordpress site I am working on, subscribers will not be allowed to see anything in the backend at all. Because of that I am creating a custom pages for the Wordpress login page that subscribers can access. On the login form there is a  "Lost Password" link.

I have managed to redirect most things to my own custom pages, but when someone enters their username in the lost password field, it sends the user an email with a link in it, which redirects them to the Wordpress backend to reset their password. I want to be able to edit that link in the email and redirect them to my own password reset page, but I can't find anywhere to hook in. Can someone give me the right action for hooking into that? I don't want to change any of the Wordpress Core code.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter you're looking for is `retrieve_password_message`.

The relevant function can be found in *[wp-login.php (starting on line 165, wp 3.2.x)](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-login.php#L158)*, the filter is applied in line 231.